# String parameter passed in javascript does not work

Tags: javascript

Just trying to understand whats going on here. Obviously a quirk of javascript, hoping someone can help explain.

**HTML:**

```
<input type="file" asp-for="TitleImageUrl" value="@_loc[Model.AddTitleImageButton]" onchange="preview('CardDynamicImage')" />

<img class="card-img-top embed-responsive-item" id="CardDynamicImage" src="@Model.CardTitleImage" onerror="this.src=''">
```

**JAVASCRIPT THAT WORKS:**

```
function preview(elementId) {
<!--The id of the element is hard coded directly. Ignore the value passed in.-->
            CardDynamicImage.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
    }
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT THAT DOES NOT WORK: Why?**

```
function preview(elementId) {
<!--Trying to pass in the id of the element does not work.-->
            elementId.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
}
```

Comment: An element *id* is not the same as the element itself. Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3434278/1048572), but don't do that! Use `document.getElementById`.

Comment: Ugh...I have some refactoring to do...thanks Bergi :)